# Console application entry points and static non-async methods

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, console-application

I have few queries on about a console application which is triggered from a scheduler. This application is an auto-mailer.

(1) To be executed from Windows Task Scheduler, any specific change is required in the methods or the entry point? I have just pointed Scheduler to the Bin\Debug path  where my .exe resides.

(2) Since the entry point (Main) is static, I had to change all methods to static. Does this have any impact on this job which is recurring. I wanted to keep all methods non-static but Console entry point is demanding static.

(3) There are two methods. First pulls data and calls the second one to send mail. I have not used async. Will this create any issue?

Comment: "but Console entry point is demanding static." - until you do `var worker - new WorkerService();`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this question is related to your earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55193987/debugging-a-windows-console-application-from-task-scheduler)

(1) To be executed from Windows Task Scheduler, no specific change is required in the methods or entry points. If your application is running from visual studio or by double-clicking the executable file, it should run from task scheduler also.

(2) To call non-static methods from your static Main(), you need to create an object of the class and call the methods using the object. Please check below.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testClassObj = new TestClass();
        testClassObj.NonStaticMethod();
        ...
    }

    public void NonStaticMethod()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

(3) No, there should be no issues there

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is related to previous but I thought it would be appropriate to post as a separate question. Is it recommended to use async on SendMail method?

Comment: That depends on whether you want to run some other code in parallel, I cannot answer it clearly without seeing your entire flow. You will anyway have to await the call to async else the main thread will exit before spawned threads do their job.